# I am new to tkinter ......Why these entries are not moving when I scrolls?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
naan = IntVar()
roti=IntVar()
dal=IntVar()
manchurian = IntVar()
makhani=IntVar()
masala_bhindi = IntVar()
chole = IntVar()
rajma = IntVar()
shahi_panneer = IntVar()
kadahi_paneer = IntVar()
masala_gobhi = IntVar()
allo_gobhi = IntVar()
matar_paneer = IntVar()
menu_roti = "Tava Roti             25 ₹/piece"
menu_dal = "Dal                       80 ₹/bowl"
menu_makhani = "Dal Makhni          110 ₹/bowl"
menu_naan = "Naan                    50 ₹/piece"
menu_manchurian = "Manchurian         110 ₹/plate"     
menu_shahi_panneer = "Shahi paneer      110₹/bowl"
menu_kadahi_paneer = "Kadhai paneer     150/bowl"
menu_masala_gobhi = "Masala gobhi      130₹/bowl"
menu_allo_gobhi = "Aloo gobhi          120₹/bowl" 
menu_matar_paneer = "Matar paneer      135₹/bowl"
menu_masala_bhindi = "Masala bhindi     110₹/bowl"
menu_chole = "Chole                 100₹/bowl"  
menu_rajma = "Rajama              150₹/bowl"
menu_chaap = "Chaap                125₹/bowl"
menu_aloo_parntha = "Aloo parantha     35₹/peice" 
menu_cheele = "Cheele                55₹/peice "
scrollbar_tk = Scrollbar(root)
list = Listbox(root, bg="wheat", fg="yellow", width=35, font=("arial", 30), yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tk.set)
list.place(x=100, y=400)
list.insert(END, "Food Items         Prices         Quantities")
list.insert(END, menu_roti, menu_dal, menu_makhani, menu_naan, menu_manchurian, menu_shahi_panneer)
list.insert(END, menu_kadahi_paneer, menu_masala_gobhi, menu_allo_gobhi, menu_matar_paneer)
list.insert(END, menu_masala_bhindi, menu_chole, menu_rajma, menu_chaap, menu_aloo_parntha, menu_cheele)
q_roti = Entry(root, font=("arial",20), textvariable = roti, fg="Black", width=10)
q_roti.place(x=525, y=115)
q_dal = Entry(root, font=("arial",20), textvariable = dal, fg="black", width=10)
q_dal.place(x=525,y=160)
q_makhani = Entry(root, font=("arial",20), textvariable = makhani, fg="black", width=10)
q_makhani.place(x=525, y=202)
q_naan = Entry(root, font=("arial",20), textvariable = naan, fg="black", width=10)
q_naan.place(x=525,y=245)
q_manchurian = Entry(root,font=("arial",20), textvariable = manchurian, fg="black", width=10)
q_manchurian.place(x=525,y=290)
q_shahi_panneer = Entry(root, font=("arial",20), textvariable = shahi_panneer, fg="black", width=10)
q_shahi_panneer.place(x=525,y=335)
q_kadahi_panneer = Entry(root, font=("arial",20), textvariable = kadahi_paneer, fg="black", width=10)
q_kadahi_panneer.place(x=525,y=380)
q_masala_gobhi = Entry(root, font=("arial",20), textvariable = masala_gobhi, fg="black", width=10)
q_masala_gobhi.place(x=525, y=425)
q_allo_gobhi = Entry(root, font=("arial",20), textvariable = allo_gobhi, fg="black", width=10)
q_allo_gobhi.place(x=525, y=470)
q_matar_panneer = Entry(root, font=("arial",20), textvariable = matar_paneer, fg="black", width=10)
q_matar_panneer.place(x=525,y=515)
q_masala_bhindi = Entry(root, font=("arial",20), textvariable = masala_bhindi, fg="black", width=10)
q_masala_bhindi.place(x=525,y=560)
q_cholle = Entry(root,font=("arial",20), textvariable = chole, fg="black", width=10)
q_cholle.place(x=525, y=605)
q_rajma = Entry(root,font=("arial",20), textvariable = rajma, fg="black", width=10)
q_rajma.place(x=525, y=650)
scrollbar_tk.config(command=list.yview)
list.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, pady=60, padx=1)
list.itemconfig(0, fg="red")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am also new to stack overflow Is this question correct?

Comment: Because the text is in listbox and the entry is in window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your listboxes to a scrollable frame.

If you would like to be able to select an item like you can in the listbox, you can change the labels to be buttons.

If you want to style the scrollbar, ttk would help.

I reused code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61588726)

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root['bg'] = 'wheat'


frame_container=Frame(root, width = 1000)
frame_container['bg'] = 'wheat'
canvas_container=Canvas(frame_container, width = 1000)
canvas_container['bg'] = 'wheat'


frame2=Frame(canvas_container, width = 1000)
frame2['bg'] = 'wheat'

scrollbar_tk = Scrollbar(frame_container, orient="vertical",command=canvas_container.yview)#, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tk.set
 # will be visible if the frame2 is to to big for the canvas
canvas_container.create_window((0,0),window=frame2,anchor='nw')


naan = IntVar()
roti=IntVar()
dal=IntVar()
manchurian = IntVar()
makhani=IntVar()
masala_bhindi = IntVar()
chole = IntVar()
rajma = IntVar()
shahi_panneer = IntVar()
kadahi_paneer = IntVar()
masala_gobhi = IntVar()
allo_gobhi = IntVar()
matar_paneer = IntVar()
menu_roti = "Tava Roti             25 ₹/piece"
menu_dal = "Dal                       80 ₹/bowl"
menu_makhani = "Dal Makhni          110 ₹/bowl"
menu_naan = "Naan                    50 ₹/piece"
menu_manchurian = "Manchurian         110 ₹/plate"     
menu_shahi_panneer = "Shahi paneer      110₹/bowl"
menu_kadahi_paneer = "Kadhai paneer     150/bowl"
menu_masala_gobhi = "Masala gobhi      130₹/bowl"
menu_allo_gobhi = "Aloo gobhi          120₹/bowl" 
menu_matar_paneer = "Matar paneer      135₹/bowl"
menu_masala_bhindi = "Masala bhindi     110₹/bowl"
menu_chole = "Chole                 100₹/bowl"  
menu_rajma = "Rajama              150₹/bowl"
menu_chaap = "Chaap                125₹/bowl"
menu_aloo_parntha = "Aloo parantha     35₹/peice" 
menu_cheele = "Cheele                55₹/peice "

listItems = [menu_roti,menu_dal,menu_makhani, menu_naan, menu_manchurian, menu_shahi_panneer,
             menu_kadahi_paneer, menu_masala_gobhi, menu_allo_gobhi, menu_matar_paneer, menu_masala_bhindi, menu_chole, menu_rajma, menu_chaap, menu_aloo_parntha, menu_cheele]


Title = Label(frame2, text = "                Food Items         Prices         Quantities", fg = 'red', bg = 'wheat', font=("arial", 30))
Title.grid()
for item in listItems:
    label = Label(frame2,text=item, fg = 'yellow', bg = 'wheat', font=("arial", 30))
    label.grid(column=0, row=listItems.index(item)+1)


q_roti = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = roti, fg="Black", width=10)
q_roti.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
q_dal = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = dal, fg="black", width=10)
q_dal.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
q_makhani = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = makhani, fg="black", width=10)
q_makhani.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
q_naan = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = naan, fg="black", width=10)
q_naan.grid(column = 1, row = 4)
q_manchurian = Entry(frame2,font=("arial",20), textvariable = manchurian, fg="black", width=10)
q_manchurian.grid(column = 1, row = 5)
q_shahi_panneer = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = shahi_panneer, fg="black", width=10)
q_shahi_panneer.grid(column = 1, row = 6)
q_kadahi_panneer = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = kadahi_paneer, fg="black", width=10)
q_kadahi_panneer.grid(column = 1, row = 7)
q_masala_gobhi = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = masala_gobhi, fg="black", width=10)
q_masala_gobhi.grid(column = 1, row = 8)
q_allo_gobhi = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = allo_gobhi, fg="black", width=10)
q_allo_gobhi.grid(column = 1, row = 9)
q_matar_panneer = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = matar_paneer, fg="black", width=10)
q_matar_panneer.grid(column = 1, row = 10)
q_masala_bhindi = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = masala_bhindi, fg="black", width=10)
q_masala_bhindi.grid(column = 1, row = 11)
q_cholle = Entry(frame2,font=("arial",20), textvariable = chole, fg="black", width=10)
q_cholle.grid(column = 1, row = 12)
q_rajma = Entry(frame2,font=("arial",20), textvariable = rajma, fg="black", width=10)
q_rajma.grid(column = 1, row = 13)

frame2.update() # update frame2 height so it's no longer 0 ( height is 0 when it has just been created )
canvas_container.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tk.set, scrollregion="0 0 0 %s" % frame2.winfo_height()) # the scrollregion mustbe the size of the frame inside it,
                                                                                                            #in this case "x=0 y=0 width=0 height=frame2height"
                                                                                                            #width 0 because we only scroll verticaly so don't mind about the width.
canvas_container.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

scrollbar_tk.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky='ns')


frame_container.grid()#.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is working now. Can I do something for you in stack overflow?? I am new to this site.

Comment: @Hashtag3 You can up vote my answer. You can also mark my answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to my answer to turn it green. You have no need to do anything else.  I'm glad my answer worked for you.

Comment: I don't even have 15 reputation sorry .. But I have ticked it..:)

Comment: @Hashtag3 Thank you, that's no problem